# node.js File upload configurations

Tags: node.js, express

No Matter how much I've searched and changed and toyed over the last 24 hours, I simply can not find the right combination of settings that allows Node.js to upload multiple files.

My setup is quite simple - I have a form interface that posts multipart content (files) to an endpoint.. lets call it: **/theendpoint**

and this end point is supposed to parse the multiple files. However, during the parsing, there are various events that need to be called once the file is uploaded.

I'm currently using the `express.bodyParser({ uploadDir:'/tmp', keepextensions:true, defer:true});` in the app configuration.

Using the following method, I am trying to parse the file, but the problem is

> Only 2 files will begin uploading, and will not complete (ie. the progress bar hangs near the end without fully completing).
>
> The other files to be uploaded by the form (item 3+) do not even begin to upload to the server.

It seems to be some sort of asynchronus holdup, however I can't properly interpret the problem. Some of the code used at the upload endpoint are as follows:

```
// This applies to /theendpoint route. Using Express.
exports.theendpoint = function(req,res){
   console.log(req.files);
   fs.readfile(uploadPath, function(err,data){

      if(err) throw err;
      fs.writeFile(newFilePath, data, function(err){
         // Series of checks and definitions
         // Database connection
         // Conditional executions

         fs.unlink(req.files.file.path, function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('Deleted');
         });
      });
   });
};
```

Obviously I've left out some of the code here. If anyone can help - is this structure workable?

You should know that items in the commented section.. ie DB connection etc. are asynchronus tasks.

Comment: I seem to have solved my own problem.

Comment: the issue was that i had removed the response code while implementing & tidying the additional code (shown as comments in this example).

Comment: the eventual solution was to add res.redirect("back") after the fs.unlink callback. It works. I'm happy :) hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after

```
fs.unlink(req.files.file.path, function(err){
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log('Deleted');
});
```

add

```
res.redirect("back");
```

and it works!